# Go k8s client overriding v11.0.0+incompatible dependency?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client

This is my Go project/module, I'm compiling with Go 1.15.4:

```
module xxx.com/xxx/xxx

go 1.13

replace (
    k8s.io/api => k8s.io/api v0.19.0
    k8s.io/apimachinery => k8s.io/apimachinery v0.19.0
    k8s.io/client-go => k8s.io/client-go v0.19.0
)

require (
    github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.4.2
    github.com/mgutz/ansi v0.0.0-20200706080929-d51e80ef957d // indirect
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.7.0
    github.com/spf13/cobra v1.1.1
    github.com/thediveo/klo v1.0.0
    github.com/x-cray/logrus-prefixed-formatter v0.5.2
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.0-20200615113413-eeeca48fe776
    k8s.io/client-go v11.0.0+incompatible
)
```

I've placed `replace`ment definition in order to use the (recent as of this writing) version 1.19.0 of the Kubernetes Go client packages.

When compiling, the Go tools always add a require for `k8s.io/client-go v11.0.0+incompatible`. Even if I manually change it to be `k8s.io/client-go v0.19.0` it gets reverted on the next build.

- can someone please explain why the v11.0.0+incompatible version keeps coming back (due to some dependency of a dependency)?
- how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried running go mod -u to update the packages and imports?

Comment: `go mod -u` gives unknown command, run go help mod for usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
go mod why <modulename>
```

For example in your case

```
go mod why k8s.io/client-go v11.0.0+incompatible
```

This will tell you who is using this module

Comment: There seems to be a mistake with how you use the versioning information, as `go mod why k8s.io/...` says "main module does not need package k8s.io/client" ... and does not need package "v11.0.0+incompatible". This looks like it's interpreting the version tag as a module name? Nota bene: the main package/module doesn't pull in the k8s client, but a subpackage of the module.

Comment: Hmm ... open issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27900 says that go mod why is slightly sub-optimal in some cases just saying "main module does not need ...". Sigh.